# How to extract values from components that have been rendered in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I'm new to React and I just started a new project to learn it. Currently I'm stuck on how to exact the value from components that have been rendered by another component. I'll give an example code to better explain myself.

Let's say I have built components Fruit and Vegetables, each of them have

```
this.state = {
   price: 0,
}
```

and later

```
this.setState({price:/*randomly generated positive integer*/})
```

and I try to encapsulate them in a new component called Base. In Base's render() function I have:

```
render() {
    return (
    <>
        <Fruit></Fruit>
        <Vegetables></Vegetables>
        <button onClick={() => this.add()}>Add Prices!</button>
    </>
    )
}
```

where as the add() function aims to add the prices of the previously rendered Fruit and Vegetables prices. I've tried to assign them an id and use DOM to grab their values but I could not reach their this.state. Is there a way to achieve this, or alternatively, what is the common practice to do this in React? Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: For this, you would usually bring the price state for each child up to the parent Base component so then you can update it in the parent. You can pass down the individual price values to the children components using props

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering though, since my Base component is simply a wrapper of everything in the project, wouldn't it cause more coupling if I include prices in Base itself?

Comment: Not really, because you would be able to reuse both Fruit and Vegetable components from anywhere in your code, (with different price passed down as props etc) if you wanted to show only one of them at a given time in different screen. But you could rename your Base component to HomeScreen or something among these words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't be able to modify react's components state outside of the component by definition. (From parent I think there's no way afaik. But if you want to update from child you could pass down a function via props, from parent to child which updates parent's state).

Simple way to overcome this could be to have prices be defined in `Base` component's state, then add function in Base component would update Base state. And you could pass prices down to Fruit and Vegetable via props.

Something along these lines:

```
function Base() {
    const [prices, setPrices] = useState({
        fruit: 20,
        vegetable: 10,
    });

    const add = () => {
        setPrices({
            fruit: prices.fruit + 10,
            vegetable: prices.vegetable + 15
        });
    }

    return (<>
        <Fruit price={prices.fruit}></Fruit>
        <Vegetables price={prices.vegetable}></Vegetables>
        <button onClick={() => this.add()}>Add Prices!</button>
    </>);
}

function Fruit({price})
{
//----
}

function Vegetable({price})
{
//.....
}
```

However, in complex application passing down props through N number of children can get tedious. In future when your application grows you might want to look at React Contexts. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thank you for the sample code and the explanation. I've got 1 more questions here: if we pass down props this way, will any modifications on price in fruit/vegetable be reflected back in their values in base, and therefore causing a DOM update?

Comment: You can't change props from component, if you need to change props from inside of the component you need to pass a function which updates parent components state as a prop to children. For example, in this case if you wanted to have `Add Prices!` button inside Fruit or Vegetables you could pass add function as a prop down to them and call the passed function from inside of Fruit or Vegetables component.

Comment: Just gonna add that when the function will be called it will cause state update in Base, which will cause DOM rerender of Base component and then it will rerender all children components, being Fruit, Vegetables and button I think.

Comment: Hi, I would like to make a follow up. Since my add() function concerns both prices from fruit and vegetables, I think I can only do the computation in Base. However, I logged the sum of their price after add() and it shows the correct value, but DOM does not update properly with the change (which is rendered in fruit/vegetables). Is there a way to get around that please?

Comment: Umm it sounds you're doing something wrong, without the code I can't tell what you're doing wrong, sorry :D

Answer (score 2):

One common practice is to define the prices in your main component and then pass those prices as props to its children.

Otherwise you could use a state managing library such as Redux to access states from anywhere in your app (this would be way too much for such a simple case)

Comment: Isn't Redux main point to have all app's state defined in one place? `To access states from anywhere` you could use React context for it no?

Comment: Sure, both Redux and React Context would do the trick

Comment: Just gonna add a note that React Context seems like a more simplier soliution for this.